# How to deal with assets in rust?

Tags: rust, assets

I have several json files which contain objects that need to be exported from the module to be used(read only) in various places in the code base. Exporting a function that reads the files and parses them and invoking it every time the objects are needed seems very wasteful. In go I'd export a global variable and initialize it in init function. So how do I go about doing it in rust?

Comment: Sounds like you should look at the lazy_static! macro.

Comment: @IanAsh It feels more like a hack rather than a solution.

Comment: Are they known at compile time? If yes, why not just evaluate them at compile time via a macro and store them in a global const?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359340/deserialize-file-using-serde-json-at-compile-time

Comment: Or convert the json file into a `json!(..)` version via `build.rs`, and then include it in your build tree as a normal `.rs` file?

Comment: @Finomnis Yes, the jsons are known at a compile time and if they are changed the package needs to be rebuilt. Situation is exactly the same as in the question you linked. I guess `build.rs` would be the most appropriate in this case. I'm not sure how to make the rust objects that will be created in `build.rs` available in other places in the code base. How exactly should I go about doing what you suggested in your last comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using this for interface definitions between different system parts. This is a known and well understood problem and is usually solved with a build script, such as in the [case of protobuf](https://docs.rs/protobuf-codegen/latest/protobuf_codegen/).

There is a very good [tutorial about how to use the build script to generate files](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/tutorial-3.html).

This is how this could look like in code.

(All files are relative to the crate root directory)

`shared_data.json`:

```json
{
    "example_data": 42
}
```

`build.rs`:

```rust
use std::{
    env,
    fs::File,
    io::{Read, Write},
    path::PathBuf,
};

fn main() {
    // OUT_DIR is automatically set by cargo and contains the build directory path
    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());

    // The path of the input file
    let data_path_in = "shared_data.json";

    // The path in the build directory that should contain the generated file
    let data_path_out = out_path.join("generated_shared_data.rs");

    // Tell cargo to re-run the build script whenever the input file changes
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed={data_path_in}");

    // The actual conversion
    let mut data_in = String::new();
    File::open(data_path_in)
        .unwrap()
        .read_to_string(&mut data_in)
        .unwrap();

    {
        let mut out_file = File::create(data_path_out).unwrap();
        writeln!(
            out_file,
            "::lazy_static::lazy_static! {{ static ref SHARED_DATA: ::serde_json::Value = ::serde_json::json!({}); }}",
            data_in
        )
        .unwrap();
    }
}
```

`main.rs`:

```rust
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/generated_shared_data.rs"));

fn main() {
    let example_data = SHARED_DATA
        .as_object()
        .unwrap()
        .get("example_data")
        .unwrap()
        .as_u64()
        .unwrap();

    println!("{}", example_data);
}
```

Output:

```
42
```

Note that this still uses `lazy_static`, because I didn't realize that the `json!()` macro isn't `const`.

One could of course adjust the build script to work without `lazy_static`, but that would probably involve writing a custom serializer that serializes the json code inside the build script into executable Rust code.

EDIT: After further research, I came to the conclusion that it's impossible to create `serde_json::Value`s in a `const` fashion. So I don't think there is a way around `lazy_static`.

And if you are using `lazy_static`, you might as well skip the entire `build.rs` step and use `include_str!()` instead:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref SHARED_DATA: serde_json::Value =
        serde_json::from_str(include_str!("../shared_data.json")).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let example_data = SHARED_DATA
        .as_object()
        .unwrap()
        .get("example_data")
        .unwrap()
        .as_u64()
        .unwrap();

    println!("{}", example_data);
}
```

However, this will result in a runtime error if the json code is broken. With the `build.rs` and the `json!()`, this will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

The general way of solving this problem in Rust is to read the assets in a single place (`main()`, for example), and then pass a reference to the assets as needed. This pattern plays nicely with Rust's borrow checker and initialization rules.

However, if you insist on using global variables:

When we apply Rust's initialization and borrow checker rules to global variables one can see how the compiler might have a hard time proving (in general) that all accesses to a global variable are safe. In order to use global variables the `unsafe` keyword might need to be used when accessing the variable, in which case you are simply asserting that the programmer is responsible for manually verifying that all accesses to the global variable happen in safe way. Idiomatic Rust tries to build safe abstractions to minimize how often programmers need to do this. I wouldn't consider the `lazy_static!` macro as a hack, it is a abstraction (and a very commonly used one) that transfers the responsibility from the programmer to the language to prove that the global access is safe.